# How to create subplots with different wspace between them in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can we create subplots with varying wspace between them. For example I am plotting 5 graphs, 2 in first row and 3 in second. I want that first row has different wspace and the last 3 have wspace = 0. I know it is possible with gridspec but I was unable to understand it, so is there any other way in subplot to do that or can somebody explain how the gridspec works, the syntax and how the parameters work to resize and place them at a particular position with other plots

```
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, -1])

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[:, :-1])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs2[:-1, -1])
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs2[-1, -1])
```

I cant understand how

```
(gs1[:-1, :])
(gs1[-1, :-1])
(gs1[-1, -1])
```

works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)` this means 3 rows and 3 columns, total 9 subplots with indexes `gs1[i,j], i - a row, j - a col`.

Look at the example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

print A[:-1, :] # get first and second rows (that is -1 means does not include last elements (last row) 
print A[-1, :-1] # from last row get all columns except last
print A[-1, -1] # get last element of array A (that is A[2][2])
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[7 8]
9
```

Read about array slicing in python: http://structure.usc.edu/numarray/node26.html